# Scala program isn't seeing dependencies downloaded via SBT

Tags: scala, cassandra, sbt, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm writing a script to try to get Cassandra and Spark working together but I can't even get the program to compile. I am using SBT as the build tool and I have all the dependencies required for the program declared. The first time I ran sbt run it downloaded the dependencies but I would get an error when it started compiling the scala code shown below:

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/vagrant/ScalaTest/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[error] /home/vagrant/ScalaTest/src/main/scala/ScalaTest.scala:6: not found: type SparkConf
[error]                 val conf = new SparkConf(true)
[error]                                ^
[error] /home/vagrant/ScalaTest/src/main/scala/ScalaTest.scala:9: not found: type SparkContext
[error]                 val sc = new SparkContext("spark://192.168.10.11:7077", "test", conf)
[error]                              ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 3 s, completed Jun 5, 2015 2:40:09 PM
```

This is the SBT build file

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
        settings(
                name := "ScalaTest",
                version := "1.0"

        )


libraryDependencies += "com.datastax.spark" %% "spark-cassandra-connector" % "1.3.0-M1"
```

and this is the actual Scala program

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._

object ScalaTest {
        def main(args: Array[String]) {
                val conf = new SparkConf(true)
                        .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")

                val sc = new SparkContext("spark://192.168.10.11:7077", "test", conf)
        }
}
```

Here is my directory structure

```
- ScalaTest
  - build.sbt
  - project
  - src
    - main
      - scala
        - ScalaTest.scala
  - target
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the problem, but you're not importing the `SparkConf` and `SparkContext` classes definition. Thus try adding to your scala file:

```
 import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
 import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

Comment: I'm a fool, there are several other dependencies I need for it to function